# Oldest ubuntu supporting Qt5

Tags: ubuntu, compilation, qt5, software-distribution

I'm developing an app which will be distributed as a binary, and the app depends on Qt5.  I will have to compile on various platforms to create apps for the major distros (I assume).

I would like to support Ubuntu - how far back can I go in Ubuntu version and still get Qt5 packages to compile against?  (I don't want to build qt5 from source, must be available as a package in the default repos for that distro)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

QT5.2 has no special dependencies.  I have built it on platforms back to 11 with no problem.  In fact, it has been successfully compiled and ported on platforms like raspberry pi with minimal problems.  Here is a list of build requirements:

Git (>= 1.6.x)
Perl (>=5.14)
Python (>=2.6.x)

Libxcb

There are even helper compilation libraries for 11.

You can find all the information at: http://qt-project.org/wiki/Building_Qt_5_from_Git

Answer (score 0):

Seems like Qt5 is supported since `13.04 raring`?

- http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&keywords=qt5&searchon=names

Comment: It is supported far further back than the current major release.

Comment: If the OP question is "is Qt5 available as a package from universe", I think @nodakai is right. If the question is "Is Qt5 buildable using a particular version of Ubuntu from source", you are right. I tend towards the former interpretation.